# How to restart phpmyadmin after configuring config.default.php

Tags: phpmyadmin, restart

I want to set default theme so i need to go into `/var/www/phpmyadmin/libraries/config.default.php`

And I don't know how to restart `phpmyadmin`.
I tried `systemctl` restart `phpmyadmin` but it told me that it wasn't able to find `phpmyadmin.service`